# Proper use of LogCat and try/catch block

Tags: android

I'm trying to use LogCat to debug a simple app that reads an XML file in my res folder.

I keep getting this error in my Eclipse LogCat window:

```
01-03 10:21:30.741: W/dalvikvm(356): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
E/AndroidRuntime(356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{tot.HelloAndroid/tot.HelloAndroid.HelloAndroid}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

This doesn't seem to helpful to me.  I am using a try/catch block like this.  Does this look ok?

```
public XmlParser() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

  try {
    XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.encounters);
    // ...do stuff...
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
  }

  //...
```

Comment: you have this activity defined in AndroidManifest.xml right?

Comment: my app has an activity defined in the AndroidManifest.xml...its just the name of my app....HelloAndroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error message is `null` (which can be the case if the error message has not been set), you try to print nothing, a simple fix is to use

```
Log.e("error",""+e.getMessage()); //or "error message: "+e.getMessage();, or whatever you want.
```

or

```
Log.e("error", String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
```

You might also want to call `e.printStackTrace()` to get more detailed information.

Comment: I don't think e.printStackTrace() will be informative.  If not, try: Log.e("error", Log.getStackTrace(e));

Comment: Why wouldn't the stack trace be informative compared to Log.getStackTrace()? They both print exactly the same information, but Log.e("error",Log.getStackTrace(e))); prints it as an error instead of a warning and with the tag "error".

Comment: I tried the 2nd option and I get 'error' 'null' in my catlog window.  Is there a way to figure out what is null?  I'm not sure if it can't find the XML file, or an element within the XML file.  - thanks

Comment: Print the StackTrace as seen at the bottom, it contains more detailed information about the error, such as in what method and on what line the error occurred. The 'message' of the error might not contain any information at all (as is the case here).

Comment: after using printStackTrace(), I see this:E/error(374):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81) --  but I don't have anything called ContextWrapper.java...unless that is something built-in.  The last error in the StackTrace that refers to my code just says: xmlParser.java line 19.  Line 19 is simply: XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.encounters);  -- where "encounters" is my encounters.xml file in my res folder.